# Unshaded box inside a shaded box

Tags: tikz-pgf

So far what I have is this: [image: this]

Which you can generate with the following script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{mdframed}
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \foreach \i /\x/\y in {
            1/1.2/0,
            2/0.6/1.0392304845413,
            3/-0.6/1.0392304845413,
            4/-1.2/0,
            5/-0.6/-1.0392304845413,
            6/0.6/-1.0392304845413,
            7/0/1.3,
            8/0/-1.3,
            9/1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
            10/1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135,
            11/-1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
            12/-1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135
        }{
            \node [coordinate] (n\i) at (\x,\y) {\i};
        }

        \foreach \i in {1,...,12} {
            \fill [orange,opacity=0.3] (n\i) circle (1);
            \fill (n\i) circle (1pt);
            %\draw [red] (n\i) circle (0.70710678118655);
            %\draw [green] (n\i) circle (2.2360679774998);
        }
    \filldraw[black, fill opacity=0.2] ($(-2,2)$) rectangle ($(2,-2)$);
    \filldraw[black, fill opacity=0] ($(-0.25,0.25)$) rectangle ($(0.25,-0.25)$);
    \draw (-2,2) node[below right] {$\mathcal{D}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \foreach \i /\x/\y in {
            1/1.2/0,
            2/0.6/1.0392304845413,
            3/-0.6/1.0392304845413,
            4/-1.2/0,
            5/-0.6/-1.0392304845413,
            6/0.6/-1.0392304845413,
            7/0/1.3,
            8/0/-1.3,
            9/1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
            10/1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135,
            11/-1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
            12/-1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135
        }{
            \node [coordinate] (n\i) at (\x,\y) {\i};
        }

        \foreach \i in {1,...,12} {
            \fill [orange,opacity=0.3] (n\i) circle (1);
            \fill (n\i) circle (1pt);
            %\draw [red] (n\i) circle (0.70710678118655);
            %\draw [green] (n\i) circle (2.2360679774998);
        }
    \filldraw[black, fill opacity=0.2] ($(-2,2)$) rectangle ($(2,-2)$);
    \draw (-2,2) node[below right] {$\mathcal{D}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
    \end{mdframed}
    \caption{An example of a Sensor Network in $\mathbb{R}^2$}
    \label{fig:network}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What I would like to achieve but have not yet accomplished is (on the left side) to remove the fill of the larger box from the inside of the smaller box, so that only the symmetric difference of the two squares is shaded.

A functionality that would benefit me (if it existed) would be to allow negative opacity; for example if I could use a script `\filldraw[black, fill opacity=-0.2] (-2,2) rectangle (2,-2);` to remove 0.2 points of opacity from the inside of the square, that would be extremely helpful. Unfortunately I need a work-around, so would anyone be able to offer me any advice? I'm trying to avoid having to draw four separate shading regions.

Comment: You can add a second rectangle to the path of your `\filldraw` command. That way the second rectangle will be subtracted from the area. Just change `\filldraw[black, fill opacity=0.2] (-2,2) rectangle (2,-2);` to `\filldraw[black, fill opacity=0.2] (-2,2) rectangle (2,-2) (-0.25,-0.25) rectangle (0.25,0.25);`

Comment: That's amazing - I didn't know that! Thanks alot

Comment: Please also see my answer for some more information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to elaborate a bit on my comment, because I feel I have not told everything without some examples. Tikz can use two different rules for determining which areas are *inside* a path. The default method is the `nonzero rule`. This rule draws an arbitrary virtual line from the area to infinity which counts the number of crossings with the path. The times the path is crossing the virtual line clockwise are counted positive, and the counter-clockwise crossings are counted negative. If the sum of these crossings is nonzero, the area is filled. The second method, the `even odd rule` is a bit more intuitive. This method also follows a virtual line from the area and simply counts the number of crossings. If the sum is an off number, the area is filled.

I've applied both options to your drawing and added a decoration so it is easy to see if the rectangle is drawn clockwise or counter-clockwise. Note that for two arbitrary coordinates `(a)` and `(b)`, the `(a) rectangle (b)` command draws a path `(a) -- (a|-b) -- (b) -- (b|-a) -- cycle`, where `(a|-b)` denotes the point where a vertical line from `(a)` and a horizontal line from `(b)` cross. So depending on where `(a)` and `(b)` are placed with respect to each other, the rectangle is drawn clockwise or counter-clockwise.

The code (I also changed the counter in your `\foreach` and adjusted some other things):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{mdframed}
        \centering
        \texttt{nonzero rule}:

        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
            \foreach[count = \i] \x/\y in {
                1.2/0,
                0.6/1.0392304845413,
                -0.6/1.0392304845413,
                -1.2/0,
                -0.6/-1.0392304845413,
                0.6/-1.0392304845413,
                0/1.3,
                0/-1.3,
                1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
                1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135,
                -1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
                -1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135
            }{
                \coordinate (n\i) at (\x,\y);
            }

            \foreach \i in {1,...,12} {
                \fill [orange,opacity=0.3] (n\i) circle (1);
                \fill (n\i) circle (1pt);
            }
        \filldraw[black, fill opacity=0.2, decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 2.5mm with \arrow{>}},postaction={decorate}]
            (-2,2) rectangle (2,-2)
            (-0.25,-0.25) rectangle (0.25,0.25);
        \draw (-2,2) node[below right] {$\mathcal{D}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
            \foreach[count = \i] \x/\y in {
                1.2/0,
                0.6/1.0392304845413,
                -0.6/1.0392304845413,
                -1.2/0,
                -0.6/-1.0392304845413,
                0.6/-1.0392304845413,
                0/1.3,
                0/-1.3,
                1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
                1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135,
                -1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
                -1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135
            }{
                \coordinate (n\i) at (\x,\y);
            }

            \foreach \i in {1,...,12} {
                \fill [orange,opacity=0.3] (n\i) circle (1);
                \fill (n\i) circle (1pt);
            }
            \filldraw[black, fill opacity=0.2, decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 2.5mm with \arrow{>}},postaction={decorate}]
                (-2,2) rectangle (2,-2)
                (-0.25,0.25) rectangle (0.25,-0.25);
        \draw (-2,2) node[below right] {$\mathcal{D}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \texttt{even odd rule}:

        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
            \foreach[count = \i] \x/\y in {
                1.2/0,
                0.6/1.0392304845413,
                -0.6/1.0392304845413,
                -1.2/0,
                -0.6/-1.0392304845413,
                0.6/-1.0392304845413,
                0/1.3,
                0/-1.3,
                1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
                1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135,
                -1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
                -1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135
            }{
                \coordinate (n\i) at (\x,\y);
            }

            \foreach \i in {1,...,12} {
                \fill [orange,opacity=0.3] (n\i) circle (1);
                \fill (n\i) circle (1pt);
            }
            \filldraw[even odd rule, black, fill opacity=0.2, decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 2.5mm with \arrow{>}},postaction={decorate}]
                (-2,2) rectangle (2,-2)
                (-0.25,-0.25) rectangle (0.25,0.25);
            \draw (-2,2) node[below right] {$\mathcal{D}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
            \foreach[count = \i] \x/\y in {
                1.2/0,
                0.6/1.0392304845413,
                -0.6/1.0392304845413,
                -1.2/0,
                -0.6/-1.0392304845413,
                0.6/-1.0392304845413,
                0/1.3,
                0/-1.3,
                1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
                1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135,
                -1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
                -1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135
            }{
                \coordinate (n\i) at (\x,\y);
            }

            \foreach \i in {1,...,12} {
                \fill [orange,opacity=0.3] (n\i) circle (1);
                \fill (n\i) circle (1pt);
            }
            \filldraw[even odd rule, black, fill opacity=0.2, decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 2.5mm with \arrow{>}},postaction={decorate}]
                (-2,2) rectangle (2,-2)
                (-0.25,0.25) rectangle (0.25,-0.25);
            \draw (-2,2) node[below right] {$\mathcal{D}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{mdframed}
    \caption{An example of a Sensor Network in $\mathbb{R}^2$}
    \label{fig:network}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

You can see that with the `even odd rule` it is easier to subtract a path from its surrounding path, whereas the `nonzero rule` provides some more flexibility at the price of intuitiveness.

This is all explained even more clearly in the [Tikz/PGF manual (version 3.0.1a)](http://ctan.triasinformatica.nl/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), section 15.5.2, page 172.

Answer (score 2):

I just realised after writing this question that I could draw the boxes first, before drawing the circles, and filling the inner box with solid white:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{mdframed}
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \foreach \i /\x/\y in {
            1/1.2/0,
            2/0.6/1.0392304845413,
            3/-0.6/1.0392304845413,
            4/-1.2/0,
            5/-0.6/-1.0392304845413,
            6/0.6/-1.0392304845413,
            7/0/1.3,
            8/0/-1.3,
            9/1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
            10/1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135,
            11/-1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
            12/-1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135
        }{
            \node [coordinate] (n\i) at (\x,\y) {\i};
        }

        \foreach \i in {1,...,12} {
            \fill [orange,opacity=0.3] (n\i) circle (1);
            \fill (n\i) circle (1pt);
            %\draw [red] (n\i) circle (0.70710678118655);
            %\draw [green] (n\i) circle (2.2360679774998);
        }
    \filldraw[black, fill opacity=0.2] ($(-2,2)$) rectangle ($(2,-2)$);
    \draw (-2,2) node[below right] {$\mathcal{D}_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \foreach \i /\x/\y in {
            1/1.2/0,
            2/0.6/1.0392304845413,
            3/-0.6/1.0392304845413,
            4/-1.2/0,
            5/-0.6/-1.0392304845413,
            6/0.6/-1.0392304845413,
            7/0/1.3,
            8/0/-1.3,
            9/1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
            10/1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135,
            11/-1.2928932188135/1.2928932188135,
            12/-1.2928932188135/-1.2928932188135
        }{
            \node [coordinate] (n\i) at (\x,\y) {\i};
        }
        \filldraw[black, fill opacity=0.2] ($(-2,2)$) rectangle ($(2,-2)$);
        \filldraw[black, fill=white] ($(-0.25,0.25)$) rectangle ($(0.25,-0.25)$);
        \foreach \i in {1,...,12} {
            \fill [orange,opacity=0.3] (n\i) circle (1);
            \fill (n\i) circle (1pt);
            %\draw [red] (n\i) circle (0.70710678118655);
            %\draw [green] (n\i) circle (2.2360679774998);
        }
    \draw (-2,2) node[below right] {$\mathcal{D}_0$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
    \end{mdframed}
    \caption{An example of a Sensor Network in two different domains $\mathcal{D}_0,\mathcal{D}_1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$}
    \label{fig:network}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Yielding the following:[image]